# Notifying wxSizer of dynamic layout changes

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have the following hierarchy for layout:

wxMDIChildFrame -> wxNotebook ->
wxScrolledWindow -> wxBoxSizer -> wxStyledTextCtrl

**GOAL:** The wxStyledTextCtrl (`CScriptWnd`) resizes itself when user adds or deletes a line or presses Shift+Enter to add another `CScriptWnd` to the  wxScrolledWindow.

The following code is when a line is added:

```
void CScriptWnd::OnNewLineAdded(wxStyledTextEvent& event)
{
    long col, line;
    PositionToXY(GetInsertionPoint(), &col, &line);

    auto ClientSize = GetClientSize();
    int Height = ClientSize.GetHeight();

    Height += TextHeight(line);

    SetClientSize(ClientSize.GetWidth(), Height);
    SetMinSize(wxSize(ClientSize.GetWidth(), Height));


    Refresh();
    
    //m_ParentWindow->FitInside(); //CScriptWnd gets smaller rather than larger
    //m_ParentWindow->Layout(); //CScriptWnd gets smaller rather than larger
    //m_ParentWindow->GetGrandParent()->Layout(); //No effect


    event.Skip();
}
```

Most work well such as the CScriptWnd resizes itself, the new script window added to wxScrolledWindow etc...

**The problem** is that the update to user interface only properly happens when the wxMDIChildFrame is resized using the mouse.
For example, if there are two `CScriptWnd` and the top one resizes itself, it overlaps with the bottom one
until the wxMDIChildFrame is resized using the mouse. Similar happens for the visibility of scrollbars such that when `CScriptWnd` client size gets larger the scrollbars only become visible when top-level window resized using the mouse.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: So far `GetParent()->FitInside()` seems to provide the best effect. The `CScriptWnd ` grows and shrinks without any problems and without any overlaps and scrollbars automatically appears or disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need

```
SetMinSize(GetSize());
GetParent()->Layout();
```

Comment: It solved the part "**if there are two CScriptWnd and the top one resizes itself, it overlaps with the bottom one until the wxMDIChildFrame is resized using the mouse.**". However, what happens now is the `CScriptWnd` grows only to the client size of `wxMDIChildFrame` and then `CScriptWnd` scrollbars appear. So `CScriptWnd` size becomes limited to  wxMDIChildFrame client height. Also the scrollbar of wxMDIChildFrame only appears when I resize the frame using the mouse. What I want is that `CScriptWnd` grow or shrink as much as it can.

Comment: @macroland `grows or shrinks as much as it can` - the size of mdi child is the size of "as much as it can".

Comment: @Igor Even when owned by a wxScrolledWindow?

Comment: _"What I want is that CScriptWnd grow or shrink as much as it can"_ this I do not understand. Should it grow indefinitely, according to newly added lines? Or grow up to some size (limited by MDI's client size or other limit)?

Comment: @catalin, yes it can grow up to users need (100 lines, maybe 1000) and when lines are deleted it shrinks (similar to Jupyter notebook). The wxScrolledWindow does the job here with scrollbars, so any number of lines can be added and when scrolled beginning or end of the `CScriptWnd` can be visible, the `CScriptWnd ` should not have any scrollbars of its own . Of course a max limit can be defined but it is not bound by MDI's client size. As I commented in the original post `GetParent()->FitInside()` seems to provide the best effect.

Comment: @macroland, so basically you don't want the scrollbar to appear, right?

Comment: @Igor, partly yes. When the client size of a `CScriptWnd`  or the total height of the script windows exceeds the initial client height of the wxScrolledWindow , I wanted the scrollbar of wxScrolledWindow to appear. The other problem was if there were two script windows and the one at the above starts changing size, it was overlapping with the script window at the below until I resized the wxMDIChildFrame with mouse, then things appeared correctly. So far using just `FitInside` does all these updates.

Comment: @macroland, so you want to operate with the keyboard only and no mouse scrolling? I think I know what you are after - the interface like a gmail reply window. Right?

Comment: Hmm, then maybe you can try the following: immediately after you have changed the size of a `CScriptWnd`, check if the scrolled-win client size is (still) exceeded. If yes, call SetScrollBars(..) with appropriate values to account for the required change of the virtual size. Then (for both cases) call GetParent()->Layout().

Comment: @Igor, not completely. The user can operate using the mouse or keyboard. Showing the scrollbar is crucial as there will be more than one script windows and their corresponding outputs. So user should be able to switch between them. The idea is very similar to how Jupyter notebook operates.

Comment: @catalin, I tried to track the total height and then update (but without `GetParent()->Layout()` ). It worked fairly well in terms of showing the scrollbars but not as smooth as `FitInside`. I initially tried `FitInside` but could not make it work for some reason. Now by removing the `Refresh` and using it as `GetParent()->FitInside` it seems to work well so far.